An application of the uniform boundedness principle to evaluate the norm.
I'm trying to show the following question:
Suppose $\{T_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is a family of bounded linear operators over a Banach space $X$ satisfying $T_0=I, T_tT_s=T_{t+s}$. And for all $x \in X$, the map
$\varphi_x:t\to T_t(x)$ is a continuous map from $[0,+\infty)$ to $X$. Show that there exist two constants $M$ and $\omega$ such that $\|T_t\|\leq Me^{\omega t}$ for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$.
The given hints say that the process can be divided into three steps:
(1)For $t\in [0,1]$ and any fixed $x \in X$, consider the properties of the map $\varphi_x$;
(2)Consider $|T_t| with Uniform Boundedness Principle;
(3)Then extend the result to $[0,+\infty)$ by $T_tT_s=T_{t+s}$.
Now I can only verify that $\varphi_x$ satisfies that $\varphi_0=0, \varphi_x\varphi_y=\varphi_{x+y}$ by the given properties of $T_t$ and that $\varphi_x$ is linear with respect to $t$. Then by the following inequalities:
\begin{equation*}
\|\varphi_x(t)\|\leq\|T_t(x)\|\leq\|T_t\|\|x\|=:C_{x,t}
\end{equation*}
and by the uniform boundedness principle, there exists $C_x$ s.t $\|\varphi_x\|\leq C_x$. Then $\varphi_x$ is continuous and further the map $t\to \|\varphi_x(t)\|$ is continuous because the following inequalities hold:
\begin{equation*}
|\|\varphi_x(t_1)\|-\|\varphi_x(t_2)\||\leq\|\varphi_x(t_1-t_2)\|\leq C_x\|t_1-t_2\|
\end{equation*}
So the function $\|\varphi_x(t)\|$ is bounded by $M_x$ over $[0,1]$. So $\|T_t(x)\|\leq M_x$. Use the uniform boundedness principle again and we have$\|T_t\|\leq M \leq M e^{\omega t}$ for some $M$.But I cant find the exact $\omega$.
Is there something wrong with my process? And how can I step forward. Initially I wanted to formulate an ODE with respect to $\|T_t\|$ so that I can get $e^{\omega t}$, but I found it unavailable then. Any method will be welcome.

Such a family of operators is also called a $C_0$-semi-group.
Your initial application of the uniform boundedness principle seems to do little. Since $\varphi_x$ is continuous, then so will $\| \varphi_x \|$ being the composition of continuous functions. Since $[0,1]$ is compact $\| \varphi_x\| $ has a maximum on $[0,1]$ (no need for the uniform boundedness principle).
But your second application of the uniform boundedness principle seems to be of help:
$$
\| T_t \| \leq M \quad \forall t \in [0,1] \tag{1}
$$
Hint 1:

 Let $t \in [0, \infty)$, then we can write $t = n + \delta$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta \in [0,1]$.

Hint 2:

 Use hint 1 and the properties of $T$ together with the submultiplicativity of the operator norm and the estimate in equation $(1)$ to estimate $T_t$

Full Solution:

$$\| T_{ n + \delta} \| \leq \| T_{\delta} \| \| T_1\|^n \leq M \cdot M^n =M \exp( \log(M) \cdot  n) \leq M \exp (\log(M) \cdot t). $$


I got you. It's verified now. Thank you.
